# unable to add additional APIs endpoint classes to GCP endpoints v2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have started an Google cloud endpoints v2 project using the starter code provided by Google which exposes one API named "echo".

My aim is to add another exposed class (one class/api name per business module). 
Once deployed, all calls to the new API are not generating a "NOT FOUND" error.

As a solution i have tried to look into the web.xml and did the below changes.

Initial WEB.XML version:

```
<!-- Route API method requests to the backend. -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have added my new servlet and tried to add a new servlet mapping as below:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/echo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserEndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/user/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now after adding the /echo/* to the initial servlet mapping, the ECHO working services stopped servicing, and the system still cannot invoke the new service.

Does anyone knows what i am doing wrong and what is the solution?
I don't think this feature is not supported by the endpoints v2 framework since it does seem a good design practice to do this separation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same servlet, using an init-param with all of the Endpoint classes you need:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.echo.Echo,com.example.echo.Echo2</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

You should not use `/_ah/api/echo/*` or `/_ah/api/user/*` in your web.xml. Instead, use `@Api(name = "echo")` or `@Api(name = "user")` and bind EndpointsServlet to `/_ah/api/*`.